# Regular expression capturing group returning broken matches

Tags: java, regex

I have this Java regex to match facebook post ids in urls:

```java
Pattern POST_ID_PATTERN =
  Pattern.compile(
    "[^/|.!=](\\d{7,}(?!.*\\d{7,})\\d+)",
    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE
  );
```

```java
matcher = POST_ID_PATTERN.matcher(url);
if (matcher.find()) {
  return matcher.group(1);
}
```

But for this URL `https://www.facebook.com/167637636622585/posts/2607815435938114/`
it gives me `607815435938114` when it should return `2607815435938114`.

A `regex101` test case: https://regex101.com/r/ya4F5K/1

Comment: You're not capturing `[^/|.!=]`.

Comment: Indeed. And I dont want to.

Comment: Why not? That's the first digit.

Comment: Oh god... you are right. My bad. Thank you!

Comment: `[^/|.!=]` is the character class, https://regex101.com/r/jSaFHA/1 The delimiter was removed PCRE. You can either extend the capture https://regex101.com/r/rotqmB/1 or use group 0. Or, you can negate the class with a negative lookbehind https://regex101.com/r/7FUD3Y/1

Comment: @sln WOW! Nice answer! Where did you learned all these tricks?

Comment: Oh, I'm just a you know, knowledgable pro. Also, you could just do this https://regex101.com/r/BcYGsA/1

Comment: I guess this would be more understandable https://regex101.com/r/jSaFHA/2

Comment: Does not match `https://pt-br.facebook.com/2700988176640479`